# Arrow accented with a dot (natural transformation)

Tags: math-mode, arrows, accents

In Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician" I came across an arrow accented above with a dot, indicating a natural transformation. I failed to find an existing symbol for this. It looks something like

```
$$\overset{\bullet}{\longrightarrow}$$
```

but the dot is smaller and close to the arrow. I want to avoid if possible constructing a custom symbol. Does something like this exist? DeteXify could not find one.

Comment: Have you checked through all the methods listed in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc) What about the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)?

Comment: `\xrightarrow{.}` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: @Werner: Before posting I tried google, Detexify, and (the arrows section of) the comprehensive list.  At Mico: Your solution (with .75 ex instead of 1 ex) is quite satisfactory.

Comment: so there is no unicode symbol for that guy ?

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to Mico's, but doesn't use `\ooalign`, since an approach without overlapping rules seems better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\naturalto}{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \normalfont\scalebox{1.2}{.}\cr
%      \noalign{\kern-.05ex}
      $\longrightarrow$\cr}
  }}%
}
\begin{document}
$F\naturalto G\overset{\text{\normalsize.}}\longrightarrow H$
\end{document}
```

This won't scale in sub/superscripts, but I can't see this as a real limitation.
The commented line shows where to act for raising or lowering the dot. The second arrow is just for comparison.

[image]

Comment: `s/newcommand/DeclareRobustCommand` and it'll work in captions, too

Comment: Thank you egreg. I've added it to http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=4872

Answer (score 3):

Revised suggestion (after receiving quite a few more details and suggestions from @egreg, and after finding a copy of "Categories for the Working Mathematician" online):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\newcommand{\dotarrow}{% to be used in math mode...
   \mathrel{\ooalign{\hss\raise.65ex\hbox{\scalebox{1.25}{\normalfont .}}%
   \kern0.35ex\hss\cr$\longrightarrow$}}}
\begin{document}
$\tau^{-1}: T \dotarrow S$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: On one and the same page (p. 24) of the book, there are at least two non-identical versions of the "arrow with large dot on top" symbol. (This may be due, in part, to the low resolution scan of the book I've found...) The form shown above has the dot resting on top of the arrow. In another version, the dot floats slightly above the arrow. If you prefer that look, use `\raise0.75ex` instead of `\raise0.65ex` when determining the dot's vertical position.

Comment: No, a simple period is used.

Comment: @egreg - OK. Thanks. (I don't have access to the publication "Categories for the Working Mathematician"...)

Comment: Actually I was wrong. I have the Italian translation, where most of the displayed formulas are taken from the original (and the font doesn't match). In inline formulas a period is used, in displayed ones there's a tiny bullet, much smaller than yours (but distinguishable from a period) and lowered.

Comment: @egreg - I just gave it another try.

Comment: It's lower than that and perhaps a bit fatter (`\scalebox{1.2}` might be). Rather than `\ooalign` I'd use `\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\scalebox{1.2}{\normalfont.}\cr\noalign{\kern-.1ex}$\longrightarrow$\cr}}`

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for these additional pointers! I've taken onboard the `\scalebox` and `\longrightarrow` elements. I've also changed the shift units from `pt` to `ex`; this will make the code (hopefully) more useful if used with font sizes other than `10pt`. I get a weird error message when trying to implement your code fully, so I'll leave it up to you if you want to supply a separate answer using your method.